# What's the rationale behind this optimization to ROC plotting?

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, vector, roc

I am reading [this Rnews document from June 2004](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf), and the article *Programmers’ Niche* from page 33 presented a way to draw the Receiver Operating Characteristic curves and optimization to it.

The first code snippet is trivial and consistent with the definition

```
drawROC.A <- function(T, D) {
    cutpoints <- c(-Inf, sort(unique(T)), Inf)
    sens <- sapply(cutpoints,
                   function(c) sum(D[T>c])/sum(D))
    spec <- sapply(cutpoints,
                   function(c) sum((1-D)[T<=c]/sum(1-D)))

    plot(1-spec, sens, type = "l")
}
```

Then the author says (with minor edits from me),

> There is a relatively simple optimization of the function that
>   increases the speed substantially, though at the cost of requiring `T`
>   to be a number, rather than just an object for which `>` and `<=` are
>   defined
>
> ```
> drawROC.B <- function(T, D){
>   DD <- table(-T, D)
>   sens <- cumsum(DD[ ,2]) / sum(DD[ ,2])
>   mspec <- cumsum(DD[ ,1]) / sum(DD[ ,1])
>
>   plot(mspec, sens, type="l")
> }
> ```

I have spent quite a while reading the optimized version, but got stuck on the very first line: it looks like the negative sign `-` preceding `T` is used to perform the cumulative sums in reverse order, but why?

Confused, I plotted the ROC produced by the two functions together to check if the results are the same.

[image]

The left plot is produced by `drawROC.A` whereas the right one is the outcome of `drawROC.B`. At first sight, they are not identical, but if you look closely, the range of the Y-axis is different, so they are actually the same plot.

**Edit:**

Now I have understood what the result of `drawROC.B` is correct (see my answer below), but I still have no idea where the substantial performance boost comes from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out. The `DD <- table(-T, D)` is meant to perform the cumulative sums in reverse order, and this is because we are calculating Pr(T > c), whereas cumulative sums of the table are counting the number of elements in T which are less than or equal to the current element.

In other words, this would also work, because Pr(T > c) = 1 - Pr(T <= c).

```
drawROC.B <- function(T, D){
  DD <- table(T, D)
  sens <- 1 - cumsum(DD[ ,2])/sum(DD[ ,2])
  mspec <- 1 - cumsum(DD[ ,1])/sum(DD[ ,1])

  plot(mspec, sens, type="l")
}
```

By the way, you can use this to add the two points (0, 0) and (1, 1) to the result of `drawROC.B`.

```
drawROC.C <- function(T, D){
  DD <- table(-T, D)
  sens <- c(0, cumsum(DD[ ,2])/sum(DD[ ,2]), 1)
  mspec <- c(0, cumsum(DD[ ,1])/sum(DD[ ,1]), 1)

  plot(mspec, sens, type="l")
}
```

As for the performance gain, notice that `drawROC.A` need to perform (asymptotically) `unique(T) * length(T)` comparisons, whereas `drawROC.A` only takes `length(T)` operations to build a table and all subsequent operations are as costly.